# Performance issue with line breaks in base64 data with Spring-ws and Castor

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-ws, castor

I have a SOAP service implemented with spring-ws 2.2.0 with a Castor 1.3.3 marshaller.
In the WSDL file there is a base64Binary element:

```
<xs:element type="xs:base64Binary" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="bytes"/>
```

With a CXF client the bytes are encoded on one line:

```
JVBERi0xLjQKJcfsj6IKNzkxIDAgb2JqCjw8L0xpbmVhcml6ZWQgMS9MIDEwMDQ1NzM1L0hbIDEwMjcxMyA0MDBdL08gNzkzL0UgMTAyNzEzL04...
```

With 9Mb file, the request is worked in about **40 seconds**.

With a SAP client the bytes are encoded with 76 char blocks:

```
JVBERi0xLjMNCiXi48/TDQolUlNUWFBERjMgUGFyYW1ldGVyczoNCjIgMCBvYmoNCjw8DQovRmls
dGVyIDMgMCBSDQovTGVuZ3RoIDQgMCBSDQo+Pg0Kc3RyZWFtDQp4nB1Su60YMQzjKByFo2gUjcIi
yBysM0MKjfD6FBfJBg5nCLL4E4DGff1+/W7Z8ze///yIKKIJEyGGgEBBQgktWIgwAgosqFCFLriQ
...
```

And Every LF is encoded with the proper xml entity `&#xA;`

```
JVBERi0xLjMNCiXi48/TDQolUlNUWFBERjMgUGFyYW1ldGVyczoNCjIgMCBvYmoNCjw8DQovRmls&#xA;dGVyIDMgMCBSDQovTGVuZ3RoIDQgMCBSDQo+Pg0Kc3RyZWFtDQp4nB1Su60YMQzjKByFo2gUjcIi&#xA;yBysM0MKjfD6FBfJBg5nCLL4E4DGff1+/W7Z8ze///yIKKIJEyGGgEBBQgktWIgwAgosqFCFLriQ&#xA;
```

With a 3Mb file the request is worked in about **2 minutes and 40 seconds** with the cpu at 100%.

Can the performance issue be related to the line breaks in the base64 stream?
Could be a Castor, a spring-ws or a JDK issue?

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that is an issue with the SAAJ implementation

Comment: The issue is with the xml entities `&#xA;`.
The parsing takes very long with a SOAP message with thousands of these entities.
If I manually remove these entities from the SOAP message the performance are very good.
To address this problem I'll try to clean the SOAP message before it gets parsed by the MessageFactory.

Comment: Have you tried this with AxiomSoapMessageFactory instead of SaajSoapMessageFactory?